# Check if box is covered by spheres

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I have an axis alligned 3D box (cuboid), and a sphere at each of its vertices (each with different radius). How can I check if all points of the box are covered by any of the spheres?

I need an algorithm that is rather fast, and not necessarily exact.
False negatives -- that is saying that the box is not covered when in fact it is -- are not a big problem, but still I would like to minimise this kind of errors. False positives are unacceptable.

Intended use is calculating volume of an object specified by a signed distance function. I'm recursively dividing space and if a given box is completely outside or inside of the object, I know I can stop recursion on this level. False negative would cause extra splitting of the box, but not an error in the result.

Comment: Maybe there's a really clever algorithm, but a pretty simple one would be to represent each sphere as an octree, compute their union, then check that the box is subsumed in the result. If you make the octree coordinate space equal to the box, ignoring chunks of spheres outside it because they're irrelevant, the final check is a constant time operation. This algorithm is approximate, but error can be arbitrarily small.

Comment: Is radius of all spheres the same?

Comment: If false positives where you claim that the box is completely covered when it is only e.g. 99% covered are also okay then you could use a Monte Carlo approach and randomly select points in the box, checking if they are included in one of the spheres. If 1000 randomly chosen points are picked with all of those 1000 points covered, then you could be reasonably confident that the box is at least 99% covered. I could quantify more (thinking of it as a problem of constructing a confidence interval for the coverage percentage) but won't bother if such false positives are unacceptable.

Comment: @MBo: No, each of them has a different radius, I added that to the question

Comment: @JohnColeman False positives are not ok. I only want to risk performance, not correctness.

Comment: @cube: Though it's kinda understood, is the box a cube/cuboid or a square/rectangle?

Comment: @displayName It's a cuboid.

Comment: One idea is to replace each sphere by the axis-aligned inscribed cube with the same center and see if the cubes cover the box -- which is fairly trivial. The inscribed cube takes up roughly 63% of the corresponding sphere, so there will be false negatives. To decrease the rate of false positives, you could replace cubes by inscribed polytopes with more faces and check if there are any points in the box outside of these polytopes -- using a linear programming solver this could be done fairly quickly.

Comment: Are you implementing one of my suggestions, or have you found something faster or more precise? (I'm exploring some additional ideas, like using the lowest/highest points in the "landscape" to create an approximation using triangles.)

Comment: @m69 I tried a simple prototype (check if opposite point is covered by any sphere or midpoint is covered by all spheres) and the code was so slow that I gave up on this (for now) and simply walk through much denser grid. Later I plan to combine both of these approaches and I will need this algorithm again.

Comment: How many times do you need this to run per second? What you describe only requires 9 multiplications, 2 additions, a division by 2 and 16 comparisons.

Comment: As many times per second as possible, this is not for a realtime application. Problem is that my main code is in python, so generally everything is slow and only the function evaluations at the grid points are compiled by Theano, so I can do them much faster than everything else.

Comment: If you can't solve a problem, try solving a simpler problem. Think on the 2d problem (circles at the corners of a square)

Comment: Hint for the 2d problem: suppose the circles do not cover the square.  Consider the complement U. The extreme points of U are circle-circle or circle-square intersections. Thus if you can prove a ball around each intersection is covered by a third circle, then U is empty, ie. the circles cover the square. There are at most 12 circle-circle intersections and 8 circle-square intersections to check.

Comment: Idea for the 3d problem: look at sphere-sphere-sphere intersections and sphere-sphere-cube intersections.

Comment: @ColonelPanic That is what m69 does in his answer, isn't it?

Comment: I added the formulas for the opposite-spheres method with a cubic box; maybe they can be of use when trying to come up with a fast vs. precise compromise.

Comment: And a simpler approximation: the sum of the squares of the radii is 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(While I'm trying to find a geometrically optimal version, here's a simple idea that's sure to work, but it may return some false negatives.)*

Consider two spheres at diagonally opposite corners of the box. Each of the spheres has 3 or more points where it intersects with the edges of the box. Seen from the opposite corner, one of these points is the furthest point inside the box on the sphere. That means that if all these points are covered by the opposite sphere, then the whole box is covered by these two spheres.

[image: sphereBox3D covered]

<sup>example 1: all points covered by diagonally opposite sphere</sup>

If the two spheres don't cover the whole box, check the other 3 pairs of diagonally opposite spheres. If one of the pairs covers the box, then it is covered by the 8 spheres. If none of the pairs covers the box, then it may or may not be covered by the 8 spheres (possible false negative).

[image: sphereBox3D not-covered]

<sup>example 2: some points not covered by diagonally opposite sphere</sup>

---

In the specific case of a cubic box, the radius of two diagonally opposite spheres which cover the whole cube with size 1 is given by these formulas:

> 0 ≤ r<sub>a</sub> ≤ 1 → r<sub>b</sub> ≥ √(2 + (1 - r<sub>a</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)
>   1 ≤ r<sub>a</sub> ≤ √2 → r<sub>b</sub> ≥ √(1 + (1 - √(r<sub>a</sub><sup>2</sup> - 1))<sup>2</sup>)
>   √2 ≤ r<sub>a</sub> ≤ √3 → r<sub>b</sub> ≥ 1 - √(r<sub>a</sub><sup>2</sup> - 2)

To avoid time-consuming calculations, using linear interpolation between a few points (including the breakpoints at 1 and √2) will give a conservative approximation. Or you can use the simpler but less precise approximation of r<sub>a</sub><sup>2</sup> + r<sub>b</sub><sup>2</sup> ≥ 3 (the blue circle on the graph below).

[image: radius of opposite spheres that cover cube]

---

There is a similar method where you consider the 4 spheres around the bottom corners of the box, find the "landscape" their surfaces create inside the box, and then find the lowest point in this "landscape". If you then do the same for the top spheres, and the minimum heights of the two landscapes sum to more than the height of the box, then the box is covered by the spheres.

You can then also check the left/right and front/rear minimum heights to see whether they add up to the width and depth of the box. If any of them do, then the box is covered by the spheres. If none does, it is unsure whether the box is covered (possible false negative). Since this method considers all the spheres at once, I think it'll give fewer false negatives than the diagonally-opposite spheres method.

[image: borders between spheres]

<sup>example 3a: finding the intersections of the 4 spheres</sup>

Seen from above, the intersection between any two spheres is the line between the two intersecting points of the circles where the spheres intersect the bottom side of the box.

[image: lowest point of 4-sphere landscape]

<sup>example 3b: finding the lowest points on the intersections</sup>

The intersections between spheres join up to form the "valleys" in the "landscape". The highest point of a valley between two neighbouring spheres is at the edge of the box, the highest point of a valley between two diagonally opposite spheres is on the diagonal between their centers. So the lowest points are where the "valleys" meet. Which of these points is the lowest, is determined by their distance to the diagonal between the centers of the two largest spheres.

[image: lowest point is zero]

<sup>example 3c: side not completely covered</sup>

If some of the "valleys" don't meet, then part of the bottom side is not covered by these 4 spheres, and the minimum height is obviously zero.

---

I've been fiddling around with code for the minimum-height method, and the geometry needed to calculate the lowest point between 4 spheres is actually quite simple:

- For the lowest point to be higher than zero, two diagonally opposed spheres need to intersect, i.e. r<sub>a</sub>+r<sub>c</sub> or r<sub>b</sub>+r<sub>d</sub> is not less than the box side's diagonal.
- The height of a sphere with radius *r* above a point that is distance *d* away from the sphere's center is √r<sup>2</sup>-d<sup>2</sup>.
- The part of a smaller sphere inside the box is completely contained within a larger sphere if the height of the larger sphere above the center point of the smaller sphere is greater than the smaller sphere's radius. The smaller sphere can then be ignored, because it has no impact on the height of the "landscape".
- Two spheres *a* and *b*, whose centers are at a distance *d* from each other, intersect at a distance d<sup>2</sup>+r<sub>a</sub><sup>2</sup>-r<sub>b</sub><sup>2</sup> / 2×d from the center of sphere *a*.

[image: sphereBox trigonometry]

Comment: I kind of reached the same conclusion, except for the last part where you (and me too) claim that *if all the points are, then the box is covered by the spheres.* While it is plausible that this is true, I kind of do not see yet what is the rock solid (proof to your superior) argument. The 2D version is very transparent.

Comment: @Matsmath I'm afraid the idea doesn't hold up. In a cube where every sphere has a radius slightly less than half the cube's diagonal, all the sides are completely covered, but the cube's center point is not covered.

Comment: I don't understand what you are claiming. If this is a problem, then this is a problem in 2D too, where it is *clearly not*.

Comment: @Matsmath That's the problem going from 2D to 3D; you can have spheres which cover the sides but which don't cover the whole volume. So my idea of reducing the problem to 2D geometry on each side won't work. Still, there's a solution hiding in there somewhere...

Comment: @Matsmath I added a safer 3D version, while I'm searching for a geometrically exact one.

Answer (score 0):

I think, due to the complexity of the problem, and since you accept false negatives, it would be a proper solution to just check if each sphere's radius is greater than half of the main diagonal (`r*r > a*a + b*b + c*c`). In this case, each sphere covers at least "its" 1/8 part of the cuboid and hence the cuboid is covered.